# How to initialize typeahead.js on multiple div element and contextually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js, typeahead

For various reasons, I need to be able to replicate an input box contextually. How does one initialize another typeahead.js instance every time a user adds another trip? I can't seem to initialize it with in the .on()

This is my current code:

html:

```
<form>
    <div class="summary">
        <div class="trip">
          <input class="state tt-input">
          ... other code ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add another trip</button>
</form>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var additional = $('.trip').html();

  $('form').on("change", '.state', function(e){
      var $contextualDiv = $(e.target).closest('div');
      var $state = $contextualDiv.find('.state');
  });

  $('#add').click(function() {
    if ($('.summary').children().length >= 5) return;
    $('.summary').append('<div class="trip">' + additional + "<div>");
  });

  $('.state').typeahead( //or $state.typeahead (that doesn't seem to work)
     {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
     },
     {
        name: 'states',
        source: bh,
      });
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to initialize typahead on dynamically created input? have you tried cloning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a function which will setup the typeahead for the given instance.
Then call that function for each newly created instance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var additional = $('.trip').html();


  $('#add').click(function() {
    if ($('.summary').children().length >= 5) return;
    var new_trip = $('<div class="trip">' + additional + "<div>")
    $('.summary').append(new_trip);
    var state = new_trip.find('.state')
    setupState(state)
  });

  setupState($('.state'))
});

function setupState(state){
    state.typeahead(
     {
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
     },
     {
        name: 'states',
        source: bh,
      });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for it. Can I ask why you need to have setupState outside of the add action?

Comment: @HC Because you want to call it outside of the add action for the initial state aswell. see `setupState($('.state'))`.